# Terminal does not open

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have tried to use this:

```
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.helloWorld', function () {
    vscode.window.createTerminal(`New terminal name`)
});
```

But, after running nothing happens.

Comment: You've registered a command, `extension.helloWorld`. Have you run the command?

Comment: yes, I do. But when I run it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function vscode.window.createTerminal only creates terminal and to show it you need to call .show() function. For example:

```
const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal(`New terminal name`);
terminal.show();
```